# javascript evaluation function for logical expression

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript string

```
logic= "(0 OR 1) AND 2"
```

and other an array

```
results[]= [true,false,true];
```

How can I map these two statements so that O gets substituted for true, 1 for false and 2 for true. and give me an output for the logical exxp that would be in this case true !.

Comment: One way would be: `logic = logic.replace(/\d+/g, function(m) { return results[m]; });`. But you could also write a proper parser. It all depends on the context and complexity.

Comment: What you're talking about is capture fields. Search google for "Javascript RegEx capture fields"